Why is my useOnClickOutside not working? Why can't the eventListener find e.target?
I am creating a useOnClickOutside hook. It's a hook that detects clicks outside of a registered ref.
The interface is as follows.
const ref = useOnClickOutside( () => { setShow(true) } );

return <div ref={ref}/>

However, there's an issue when rendering the DOM conditionally. When I click on one of the children of the ref, and that child changes to another DOM, it seems like the ref is considered not to contain that DOM. I don't know why this is happening.
const Card = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  const ref = useOnClickOutsideV2(
    () => {
      console.log('callback');
      setShow(true);
    },
    { enabled: !show },
  );

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      onClick={() => {
        console.log('onclick');
        setShow(false);
      }}
    >
      {show ? <div>show</div> : <input defaultValue="hi" />}
    </div>
  );
};

type Options<T> = {
  ref?: RefObject<T> | RefObject<T>[];
  events?: string[];
  enabled?: boolean;
};

export const useOnClickOutsideV2 = <T extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement, E extends Event = Event>(
  callback: (e: E) => void,
  { ref = [], events = ['click', 'touchstart'], enabled = true }: Options<T> = {},
) => {
  const [refs, setRefs] = useState<RefObject<T>[]>([ref].flat());
  const callbackRef = useRef(callback);

  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  const _ref = useCallback(
    refCallback((node: T) => setRefs([...refs, { current: node }])),
    [],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    const handler = (e: any) => {
      console.log(refs[0].current?.contains(e.target), e.target);
      if (refs.every(({ current }) => !current?.contains(e.target)) && enabled) {
        callbackRef.current(e);
      }
    };

    const removeEventListeners = () => {
      events.forEach(type => {
        document.removeEventListener(type, handler, true);
      });
    };

    events.forEach(type => {
      document.addEventListener(type, handler, true);
    });

    return removeEventListeners;
  }, [refs, enabled, ...events]);

  return _ref;
};

The console output for the above code is as follows.
onclick
false HTMLButtonElement
false HTMLButtonElement
callback

I don't understand why the result of contains for e.target (HTMLButtonElement) is false.
I thought that even if the button element disappears due to re-rendering, the addEventListener callback would execute before that, so it should be able to detect the button element.
Another thing I'm curious about is that if I set the capture option to true in addEventListener, it works correctly. Why is that?
If I set the capture option to true, the addEventListener callback executes before the onClick props. I understand this part. However, I don't understand how the change in execution order affects the functionality.
This is the demo link for the above.
I'm sorry for my poor English.
